# generate php code from wsdl

Tags: php, web-services, wsdl

I have a bunch of webservices that I need to write PHP clients for. Now I can manually write wrappers for each of the WSDL files but i wanted to see if there is a tool that can help me by generating the wrappers in PHP.

Any idea if there are any tools that do this?

Answer (score 5):

try this-> http://www.urdalen.no/wsdl2php/ it generates php wrapper from wsdl source

Comment: can't run pear on my shared hosting account :(

Comment: You can (and should) run wsdl2php on your local machine and upload the resulting php. PS: it doesn't need PEAR, just extract http://www.urdalen.no/wsdl2php/releases/wsdl2php-0.2-pear.tgz

Answer (score 3):

You may try https://www.wsdltophp.com
It is convenient to genetate php class from URI

And the author is @Mikaël DELSOL.
It is fantastic!

Answer (score 2):

Try `Zend_Soap`:

- http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.soap.html
- http://www.phpriot.com/articles/zend-soap